# Vaadin dashboard without charts

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin

I'm planning to build a dashboard-type application. I want to ask whether there's a Vaadin Dashboard Sampler without the Charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always just remove the charts from the dashboard demo if you want to use that as a base for your project.

Another good way to bootstrap a project is to use the Maven archetypes: https://vaadin.com/maven#archetypes

The `vaadin-archetype-application-example` archetype is a good starting point for a dashboard with a responsive menu.